# How to code this using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

HTML:

```html
<label>Estimated value of property:</label><input type="text" value="" id="prop_value"/>
```

How to get the value of "prop_value" and display it here when typing the value:

```
<p>You told us the estimated value of your property is: "prop_value"</p>
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
You told us the estimated value of your property is: <span id="output"></span>
```

Plain javascript [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DsqXs/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("prop_value").onkeyup=function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=this.value
  }
}
```

jQuery [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kTwzK/)

```
$('#prop_value').bind('keyup', function() {
  $("#output").text($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Why `.innerHTML` instead of `.nodeValue` :(

Comment: Why .nodeValue instead of the widely used and understood innerHTML?

Comment: thank you sir but the code depends on the button when clicked right? is there any solution that when i input a value in the textbox it will instantly display on the output..

Comment: Ohh Sorry sir, This is the scenario: when the user input a value in the textbox it will instantly display in <span id="output"></span>

Comment: Yes I realise this now. Fixed as you can see in the DEMOs - I also updated your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

using javascript you can fetch the textbox value i.e,

```
var val=document.getElementById("prop_value").value;
```

and use 'val' to show in proper location

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can get the value of input tags this way:

```
$("#tagID").val();
```